# How to install pygame on virtualenv of python 3.4 on Ubuntu (PyCharm IDE)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, virtualenv, pycharm

As the regular package of pygame is for only the python 2.7, I did some research and found out how to do it for python 3.4.
But when I opened PyCharm, I discovered that pygame is just installed in python 3.4 and not in the virtualenv of python 3.4.

When I go to Project Interpreter setting on the PyCharm, I find too many packages with the word pygame that can be installed but not just pygame. But the package named pygame is present on both python 3.4 and 2.7 but not in virtualenv of python 3.4.
How can I install it on the virtualenv of python 3.4?

Comment: You should *activate* the `virtualenv`, then install it within that environment.

Comment: And how to do that? Please elaborate, I'm new to this.

Comment: The only way I found was to install it globally and then create virtual environment that inherited global settings. Sketchy but works

Answer (score 0):

Install the required dependencies and mercurial

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-numpy libsdl-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev \
  libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsmpeg-dev libportmidi-dev \
  libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev mercurial
```

activate your environnement

```
source yourenv/env/bin/activate
```

grab the official pygame repository

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

build it

```
cd pygame
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

returning

```
yourenv/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pygame-1.9.2b8-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg
```

have fun